# 2 queries in jquery ajax call?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I am trying to retrieve some data from a Mysql database and put the results in a form.

it works fine when i query the database once and return a result. 
But when i use the result to run another query and then try to return the result i get a 500 error?

The script and its load-data.php file looks like this :

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("button").click(function(){
    var dataCount = $('#curr_pair').val();
    //console.log(dataCount);
    var var_data = "";
                     $.ajax({
                         url: "http://192.168.2.8/wp-content/plugins/trader/load-data.php",
                         type: 'POST',
                          data: ({  dataNewCount: dataCount }),
                          dataType: 'json',
                          success: function(data) {
                              //console.log(data[1]);
                              //var dataObj = JSON.parse(data);
                              console.log(data);
                              //var test = data;
                              //console.log(test);
                              $("#input").val(data[0]);
                              $("#input1").val(data[1]);
                             //$('#result').html(data)
                          }
                      });
 


$("#comments").load("../wp-content/plugins/trader/load-data.php", {
      dataNewCount: dataCount
    });




  });

});



  </script>
```

```html
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$username ="XXXXX";
$password = "XXXXX";
$database = "XXXX";

$conn = mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password,$database);
$conn1 = mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password,$database);
$dataNewCount = $_POST['dataNewCount'];


$sql = "SELECT bid,ask,curr_pair FROM wp_ticker WHERE wp_ticker.curr_pair = '$dataNewCount' LIMIT 1";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   While ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
     $val1 = $row['bid'];
    }
 }
 
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($conn);
$dataNewCountfirst3 = substr($dataNewCount, -3, 3);
if ($dataNewCountfirst3 !== "EUR"){
 $geteuro = $dataNewCountfirst3."EUR";
}


$sql = "SELECT bid,ask,curr_pair FROM wp_ticker WHERE wp_ticker.curr_pair = '$geteur' LIMIT 1";;
$result = mysqli_query($conn1, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
 //echo $result2->bid;
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $val2 =$row['bid'];
  

 }
  
} 

$data = ["$val1", "$val2"];
echo json_encode($data);
```

When i remove the second query, it works fine, but i need to run it because depending on the result of the first query, i need some more info from the same database table.

Comment: you are closing connection after first query and using the same (already closed) connection for second query.

Comment: 500 error generally means you have an error in your PHP code which, in this instance you are closing your connection.

Comment: @NobbyNobbs - The OP is not using the same connection. The OP is, for some unknown reason, creating two connections and the two queries are using different connections.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, oops, you're right. i've been reading not enough attentiive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going about this all wrong, why do you have two connections? You can use a single connection to run multiple queries.

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$username ="XXXXX";
$password = "XXXXX";
$database = "XXXX";

$conn = mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password,$database);
$dataNewCount = $_POST['dataNewCount'];


$sql = "SELECT bid,ask,curr_pair FROM wp_ticker WHERE wp_ticker.curr_pair = '$dataNewCount' LIMIT 1";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
          $val1 = $row['bid'];
        }
}

mysqli_free_result($result);

$dataNewCountfirst3 = substr($dataNewCount, -3, 3);
if ($dataNewCountfirst3 !== "EUR"){
  $geteuro = $dataNewCountfirst3."EUR";
}


$sql = "SELECT bid,ask,curr_pair FROM wp_ticker WHERE wp_ticker.curr_pair = '$geteur' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
  //echo $result2->bid;
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $val2 =$row['bid'];
  }
}

mysqli_close($conn); 

$data = ["$val1", "$val2"];
echo json_encode($data);
```

- You also had an extra `;` at the end of your second `$sql`.
- You should use [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to debug your mysqli code.
- You had a capitalised the 'w' in `while` (not an error but you should remain consistent).

I really think you should read up on the basics of [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

**Note:** Requests can be spoofed. As a result I think you should validate your input data.